# Probability with replacement of exactly (and at least) m repeats in n events of even probability k?

Tags: probability, birthday

What is the probability with replacement of seeing *exactly* m repeats in n events of even probability k?

E.g., Assume birthdays are evenly distributed across 365 days, what is the probability that *exactly* 5 people will share a birthday among 100 randomly selected persons with birthdays?

Next, what is the probability with replacement of seeing *at least* m repeats in n events of even probability k?

E.g., Assume birthdays are evenly distributed across 365 days, what is the probability that *at least* 5 people (5 or more) will share a birthday among 100 randomly selected persons with birthdays?

Thanks.

Comment: What about the case when two sets of 5 people share birthday, eg. 5 people are born on 5th February and 5 people are born on 27th January?

Comment: Next. Where is your attempt to answer these questions ?

Comment: @Stefan4024: That is counted as a success as "exactly 5 people will share a birthday, February 5." [@]callculus: Does this forum only answer if I first attempt to answer?